# The cellClass property defined in columnDefinitions is not working

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with no frameworks. The cellClass property defined in columnDefinitions is not working. I defined a function as shown below, but it is never called. I tested it in ag-grid-react and it was working fine.

```
cellClass: function (params) {
        console.log(params)
        if (params.colDef.colId === "") {
          return "border-top";
        }
        if (params.value === undefined) {
          return "border-right";
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Make sure you add the `cellClass` function to the `columnDef`. Take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/MJsmmvRCcvfjQqnz) example.

Comment: Thanks for the response Viqas. I am sure that the cellClass function is being added to columnDef only. As a workaround, I used cellClassRules instead of cellClass and it is working now. But still not sure why cellClass is not working

Comment: The same situation: the  CellClass not work, but cellClassRules is working good.
I note, that
{headerName: ''a, field: 'field_a', cellClass: getCellClassFunc}
{headerName: ''b, field: 'field_b', cellClass: getCellClassFunc}
Result set return the field_a, and not return the field_b.
For field_a cellClass not working, but for field_b - working.